# What is this method of dividing a plane called?

Tags: geometry, terminology, recursive-algorithms

I have an idea of a method for recursively dividing a plane, and as I'd like to do more research about this algorithm and the set of points that it produces, I'd like to know what it's formally known as.

1. In a plane $X$, consider the set of four points $P$ = {$P_1..P_4$} that form an irregular quadrilateral.
2. Consider the set $L$ of lines that can be drawn through these points, {$\overleftrightarrow{P_1P_2}$, $\overleftrightarrow{P_3P_4}$, $\overleftrightarrow{P_1P_4}$, $\overleftrightarrow{P_2P_3}$, $\overleftrightarrow{P_1P_3}$, $\overleftrightarrow{P_2P_4}$}.
3. Consider any points defined by intersection of the lines in $L$, such that these points that do not already exist in 
   $P$. Because any two of the quadrilateral's sides are nonparallel, the lines passing through the sides will intersect at the two "new" points $P_5$ and $P_6$.  The diagonals of the quadrilateral will also intersect at a new point $P_7$.  Add these points to $P$.
4. Consider the line $\overleftrightarrow{P_5P_6}$, as well as any lines that can be drawn through ($P_5$, $P_6$, or $P_7$) and any of the other points in $P$, such that these new lines are not collinear with the existing lines in $L$.  Add these lines to $L$.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until no more new lines can be added to $L$, that is, no new intersections are formed by constructing lines from the existing intersections.  (This may be infinite, but I haven't proven that yet.)

What is this method of space division called?

Comment: Do you also intersect the diagonals $\overleftrightarrow{P_1P_3}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{P_2 P_4}$?

Comment: @JairTaylor, yes.  Any pair of points has a line going through it, and any two lines have an intersection.

Comment: So you'll probably get three new points in Step 3, corresponding to intersecting the diagonal lines and the two pairs of lines going through the opposite sides.

Comment: @JairTaylor, I've modified the question to include the point formed by the diagonals' intersection.

Comment: Just playing around with the pictures you get, I think you get infinitely many points, and you can get points arbitrarily close together.  You might even get a set dense in the plane.

Comment: @JairTaylor, yes, it "looks" infinite, but I'd like to prove that or find an existing proof.  So, what's this called?  I'm sure I'm not the first person to identify this behavior of a set of recursively defined linear equations.

Comment: I haven't heard of it before, but maybe someone else knows.

Comment: You won't find a proof that it's infinite without resorting to Euclid's 5th Postulate, because it's easy to come up with a finite set of points (7, to be exact) that satisfy the requirements in a projective plane (look up Fano plane). I think the limit is necessarily infinite in Euclidean space, assuming you start with no parallel lines.

Comment: Here's a sketch of a proof that it's infinite.  Let $C_n$ be the convex hull of all of the points in the $n$th step.  Then intersecting any two nonparallel, non-adjacent edge-lines of the polygon $C_n$ will give a point outside $C_n$, by convexity.  So $C_n \subsetneq C_{n+1}$.

Comment: @PaulZ, I don't think the "no parallel lines" assumption makes it infinite; it's finite if the initial quadrilateral is a kite, and that doesn't have any parallel sides.  It's something to do with the irregularity.  Any idea what this is called?  Like, what do we call a graph where the intersections of edges are nodes?

Comment: @sigil: For the kite, there are still parallel lines involved later on, even if the kite itself has no parallel sides. It'd the regularity early on which leads to parallel lines later in the process, and if you don't think projectively, you will not get new points of intersection out of these. If you do things projectively, or consider a slight perturbation of your input points, then the (almost) parallel lines will intersect at (or “close to”) infinity, and the argument by Jair sounds good again.

Comment: @MvG, it sounds like you're saying that Jair's proof works with irregularity of the initial quadrilateral.  I agree that extending the non-adjacent, non-parallel sides of $C_n$ yields a point outside of $C_n$, but I'm not sure how to prove that no $C_n$ is a triangle or regular quadrilateral.

Comment: I considered the original quadrilateral not only to be irregular, but in general position. That should be enough to avoid all parallelisms. I must confess that I hadn't considered the case of the triangle, though. But after all, @Jair only calld it a *sketch* of a proof.

Comment: Did you try to reverse the question: what are the finite sets you can build this way? I can only imagine solutions of 3 and 5 points (plus the trivial solutions where all the points or all the points but one are aligned)

Comment: @PaulZ Fano plane is not a valid solution, some intersections can be added

Comment: @Bilou06 No, they can't. That's the point of a projective plane; any two points have a line between them, and any two lines intersect in a point already in the plane. There's no way to get outside it by drawing more lines between existing points, and intersecting them.

Comment: @PaulZ Do we talk about this : [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fano_plane.svg] ?
It verifies the properties defined by sigil, but not in the Euclidian plane.